# Why does Prototype of a function has to be its child?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Person(){}
person1 = new Person()
console.log(person1.constructor === Person) //true: makes sense

console.log(Person.prototype.constructor === Person) //true: Why

console.log(Person.prototype instanceof Person) //false: Why
```

In above code snippet, `person1` object was created using `Person` constructor. The constructor of `person1` object is `Person` which makes sense to me.

But when `Person` was created `Person.prototype` was also created.

For many years I had thought that constuctor of `Person.prototype` is `Object`. But today I found out its actually `Person` itself.

Honestly, I am not able to digest this revelation.

Why does `Prototype` of a function has to be its child? What is the thought behind it?

Also, weird enough: `Person.prototype instanceof Person === false`.

Please explain.

Comment: "*But today I found out its actually `Person` itself.*" it's the literal *function* `Person`, not an *instance* of `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript defined that the default object on a function's prototype property would have constructor property and that it would refer back to the function.

Which is why you see

```
Person.prototype.constructor === Person // true
```

Now,

```
Person.prototype instanceof Person
```

**return false** because `Person.prototype` is not instance of Person but is an object defined for Person itself. prototype object has two properties `constructor` which points to the Person object itself as specified above and `__proto__` .

However if you check

```
person1 instanceof Person
```

it would return you true

Comment: Person.prototype is not instance of Person but is Person itself? Person === Person.prototype?

Comment: @i_read_terms_and_services, no thats not true, I updated my answer. Person.prototype is an object defined for the Person constructor function one of whose property matches the Person function itself

Comment: `__proto__` which is used to point to the parent function prototype from which Person is inherited which in this case the Function_...Not sure why you mention this. This is true for every object, prototype or not.

Comment: It's mentioned because `Person.prototype` **is not** an **instance** of `Person`. Think of `prototype` as the blueprint for what all `Person` instances will have.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `person1` doesn't have a `.constructor` property itself, **it is inherited from `Person.prototype`**. And that's the whole reason why `Person.prototype.constructor = Person` - not because the prototype object was constructed via `Person` (it was not), but because it makes sense for `person1` to inherit this value.